# Capistrano Puma AWS can't seem to pass RVM check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano, puma, rvm-capistrano

I am having trouble connecting Rails webapp to Amazon AWS codedeploy this is the result of:

pachanga:~/workspace (master) $ ssh -v deploy@13.59.79.103

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 13.59.79.103 [13.59.79.103] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 28:6c:c4:0c:e8:86:ee:c1:70:4e:35:cf:b3:29:86:61
debug1: Host '13.59.79.103' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am following a tutorial here [the tutorial](https://github.com/rkmmanivannan/rails-ec2-configuration/blob/master/method1/application.yml)

I have authorized_keys and it has the does have the ssh in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it 
the vi editor was deleting the first character in the ssh